# PHP email content different on PC and iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, email, unicode

I send an email (in HTML format) in PHP using the **phpmailer** library.

My email is displayed correctly on PC and iPhone, no accents or other problems.

But I noticed a concern in content:

Indeed, the body of my email contains the characters "**=da**". On PC, I see "**=da**" but on iPhone, these 3 characters are replaced by "**Ú**".

The problem appears only in the body of my mail. If I display "**=da**" in the email subject, I see correctly on PC and iPhone.

NB : my code files are in UTF-8 and I make a utf8_decode the content of my mail before sending it (and I remember that I have no worries or other accents).

Comment: are you setting the mail mime type to allow utf8 characters etc?

Comment: I'm using the phpmailer library.

I use utf8_decode on my email content because in default, the charset is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: well the pc is obviously using a different content charset thats why its displaying =da rather than the Ú so it would seem its decoding it to an asci code not recognised by either the font or the charset specified for the mailbody.  The iphone must be ignoring it and just displaying the relevent character.  Try overriding phpmailers default charset.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to see `=da` or `Ú`. You've told us what you are seeing, but you haven't told us which you would expect to be correct.

Comment: I'va added 
**$phpMailer->CharSet= 'ISO-8859-1';**
but the result is the same.

I would see **=da** because it's what I write in my mail !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=xx`, with two hex digits is commonly seen in emails that use 'Quoted Printable' encoding.

Since you're using UTF-8, you won't be using quoted printable encoding, but it sounds like the iPhone may be doing the conversion anyway. This may be a bug in the iPhone email client.

My suggestion would be to switch to quoted printable mode. In phpMailer, you would do it like this:

```
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
```